# I have a list of numbers that are sometimes consecutive - how to get a list of ranges from it?

Tags: python, list, range, data-conversion, simplify

### *Motivation:*

A list of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` is expressible as `range(1,11)` and `in` checks are near [constant time computations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/7505395) if checked against ranges. Big-ish lists of numbers can be simplified if expressed as list of `range()` objects using fewer bytes then used by storing all of them as numbers in a list.

```
# what I have:
numbers = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50] 

# what I want:
ranges = [range(1,3), range(5,6), range(7,11), range(13,16), range(42,51)]
```

### *(Self answered) Question*:

How can I move from a list of numbers to a list of ranges to facilitate smaller storage and faster `in` checks - for consecutive numbers?

---

Inspired by

- [Find index of longest continious sequence in list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72042054/find-index-of-longest-continious-sequence-in-list-python)
- [How to transform a list of numbers into a list of ranges of consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976532/how-to-transform-a-list-of-numbers-into-a-list-of-ranges-of-consecutive-numbers) (which would take the ranges and string-format them)
- my answer to [Concatenate and simplify a list containing number and letter pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72012021/concatenate-and-simplify-a-list-containing-number-and-letter-pairs/72012246#72012246) where I could have used this to merge  consecutive `ord(letter)`'s of `"abcd"` into `"a-d"`

Answer (score 2):

Another version, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby


lst = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda k: k[0] - k[1]):
    start = next(g)[1]
    end = list(v for _, v in g) or [start]
    out.append(range(start, end[-1] + 1))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[range(1, 3), range(5, 6), range(7, 11), range(13, 16), range(42, 51)]
```

Comment: that is way cooler :)

Answer (score 1):

There should be ways to leverage *itertools.takewhile* or *itertools.groupby* (using boolean conditional grouping) - the simplest way without any imports I came up with is:

### Generator:

```
def get_consecutive_ranges(numbers: list[int]):
    """Takes an input of integers in a list, yields the 
    ranges of consecutive numbers that form the list."""
    if not numbers:
        return []

    k = []
    start,stop = None,None
    for num in numbers:
        if stop is None:
            start, stop = num, num
        elif stop == num-1:
            stop += 1
        else:
            yield range(start,stop+1)
            start, stop = num, num

    yield range(start,stop+1)
```

### Test:

```
data = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,50]

list_of_ranges = list(get_consecutive_ranges(data))
print(list_of_ranges)
```

to get

```
[range(1, 3), range(5, 6), range(7, 11), range(13, 16), range(42, 51)]
```

---

### Application for letter ranges:

```
letters = "abcghijklmpqrs"
lgroup = [f"{chr(min(r))}-{chr(max(r))}" 
          for r in get_consecutive_ranges(map(ord, letters))]
print(lgroup)
```

to get

```
['a-c', 'g-m', 'p-s']   # from  "abcghijklmpqrs"
```